# Android dependency 'com.android.support:support-compat' has different version for the compile (25.1.0) and runtime (25.3.0) classpath

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

```
**Android dependency 'com.android.support:support-compat' has different version for the compile (25.1.0) and runtime (25.3.0) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution**
```

The Android studio version 2.3.3, and gradle version 3.5 is the case, the project is no problem, but now I use the Android studio3.0 appear this error. Please comment. Thanks

Comment: paste your gradle app code

Comment: The error is very clear "You should manually set the same version" change everything from 25.1.0 to 25.3.0

Comment: My gradle should be no problem, I took him from Android studio version 2.3.3 switch, I listed on the 2.3.3 version can run without error, but in this version 3.0 came this strange errors.

Comment: @user6412545 Did you solve it?

Comment: I've solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Run a Gradle dependency,

```
./gradlew -q dependencies <module-name>:dependencies --configuration compile
```

Example:

```
./gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies --configuration compile
```

It will show you what is the wrong, and if you change it the error disappeared after removing.

Comment: Hi,I ran the gradle dependency command and  I'm posting the screenshot url here http://imgur.com/dL35BaN . I guess that there's something wrong with GCM. Is there any work around?